# Android, setting the theme in the style does not work

Tags: android, material-design, android-theme

I know that

> A style specifies attributes for a particular type of view. For example, one style might specify a button's attributes. Every attribute you specify in a style is an attribute you could set in the layout file. By extracting all the attributes to a style, it's easy to use and maintain them across multiple widgets.

> A theme defines a collection of named resources which can be referenced by styles, layouts, widgets, and so on. Themes assign semantic names, like colorPrimary, to Android resources.

So, i suppose that I can set the `theme` attribute from a style file.

Why doesn't this work?

```
<!-- Customize your theme here. -->
<item name="toolbarStyle">MyToolbarStyle</item>
...

<style name="MyToolBarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="MyToolbarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="theme">@style/MyToolBarTheme</item>
</style>
```

Instead this works correctly:

```
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
    android:id="@+id/homeToolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/MyToolBarTheme" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that the `theme` attribute is not set if the defining style is itself set by a theme, but only when the style is set in the designer.

The `materialThemeOverlay` attribute on the other hand works correctly and actually applies the theme.

I found a comment in a material design theme definition:

```
<style name="Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary">
<item name="android:elevation" ns2:ignore="NewApi">@dimen/design_appbar_elevation</item>
<item name="android:background">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
<item name="titleTextColor">?attr/colorOnPrimary</item>
<item name="subtitleTextColor">@color/material_on_primary_emphasis_medium</item>
<!-- Note: this theme overlay will only work if the style is applied directly to a Toolbar. -->
<item name="android:theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary</item>
```

So, in my case, this works as expected:

```
<!-- Customize your theme here. -->
<item name="toolbarStyle">MyToolbarStyle</item>
...

<style name="MyToolBarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="MyToolbarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/MyToolBarTheme</item>
</style>
```

---

### Update

How the style and theme are applied to the views is highly dependent on how the views are implemented.

`materialThemeOverlay` is used inside the material view source code, so to know exactly the effect of the theme style or attribute, you should look into the view source code.